# X509 certificate error for HTTPS on BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, x509

I want to send a request to HTTPS adapter through BizTalk server 2009. My BizTalk adapter is dynamic and it's takes configuration details from database instead of directly mentioning it on server.

I have installed X509 certificate in my browser and imported it in MMC.

I am getting following error in my BizTalk

> A message sent to adapter "HTTP" on send port "sndHL7" with URI "https://xxxxxxxxx/imm/test (https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/imm/test)" is suspended. 
>    Error details: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

I searched for this error, but every where I got following response only :

> **Error**: – Details: “The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
>
> **Solution**: The error message normally occurs if the client certificate is not configured correctly.  You should check that you have configured your client certificate in certificate store under BizTalk service account that hosts the HTTP adapter.

I am not getting how to configure that certificate in proper certificate store. I have 3 files wih extension .cer, .cer and .pfx. The file with extension **.pfx** requires password to install it in any store.

Also, how to configure certificate under BizTalk service Account? Should I select "Service Account" while adding snap in in MMC and then select BizTalk service from the list of services.

Answer (score 1):

The two .cer files must be the root authority and server certificates and you must trust them.so you need to place them in your LOCAL MACHINE- Trusted Root Certification store. (use MMC)

Now the .pfx file will have the client authentication certificate that you will be passing into get authenticated. Import this certificate to LOCAL MACHINE,Personal (or MY certificate store if using command line) check private key as exportable.

Now allow BizTalk service account access to the private key of this certificate.

MMC use add snap in and add local machine.

select the client certificate in Personal right click- AllTasks- Manage private keys. Now add your BizTalk service account as a user and give access.

Or else use winhttpcertcfg tool in command line

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about biztalk but if you are presenting a cert you need the associated private key. A cert is like a photo ID. It is hard to forge, but it still doesn't prove your identity unless you can present your face for someone to compare with the ID. Assuming the file extensions match the actual format of the files, the cer files are either DER, BER or PEM encoded certificates without the private key. So you need the pfx file. So if the proposed solution from the error message is correct, you need to find that password and install the certificate and private key from the PFX file into the store.